# Java Math.Pow method

Tags: java, pow

```
monPay = (amtFin * amtI)/((1-(1+amtI)*Math.pow(-n,-n)));
```

I am using this code but it is not calculating Math.pow(-n,-n) correctly. It seems like it is Math.pow(-n,-n) is calculating to 0.0. All variables have type `double`.

Comment: What are the types & input values here?

Comment: Value of `n` would definitely help.

Comment: What is the type of n?

Comment: For `n >= 149`, `Math.pow(-n,-n)` *will* be zero. If you're trying to express a formula as code then explaining the maths here may help identify your mistake.

Comment: This might help you: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#pow(double, double)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to compute monthly loan repayments based on the principal amount etc. However, your formula is wrong: the `(1+amtI)*Math.pow(-n,-n)` should be `Math.pow(1+amtI,-n)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. New to java and was making myself a mortgage calculator from the user inputting values. But now it works =)

Answer (score 1):

What happens is that the value of `pow(-n,-n)` is too low to be represented as a `double` (the minimum non-zero double in absolute value is about 10E-323).

You may work with [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) instead, but note that computations with `BigDecimal` are slower.